# List file locations pom files

Tags: maven, command-line, command-prompt, pom.xml

I'm trying to script some operations. It would be very useful if I could list all pom file locations in a project (parent and modules). Unfortunately I have not been able to find any example yet. Is this impossible?

edit: It might not have been clear but I was looking for a maven command or plugin.

Comment: Have you tried `grep`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why do you need the pom file locations?

Comment: There is a legacy release script that is application specific because the locations are hardcoded. I was wondering if maven could spit out those locations therefore making the script generic.

Answer (score 0):

`mvn dependency:tree` lists the dependencies of all modules of the current project. Yet this does not include the pom file locations.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar for the pom files.